# how to display foreign key fields using asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4

Basically I wanted to display foreign key fields in asp.net cshtml. I have two tables roles and admin respectively. The foreign key relationship shows that for every admin there is a Role which has to be set.
I have done the part of adding role using role name. But when it comes to deleting or updating and such functionality I am not able to figure out the way to display the role name or other role details instead of roleId.  I understand the concept of the doing, yet I do not get the right answer in asp.net mvc.

The following code for the cshtml, where I wanted to show the role name instead of role id.

```
@model IEnumerable<FastFactsTestPortalMVCApp.Models.Administrator>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ViewAdmin";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutAdmin.cshtml";
}

<h2>ViewAdmin</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AdminId)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AdminFirstName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AdminLastName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AdminEmail)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AdminUserName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AdminPassword)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AdminContactNumber)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AdminDesignation)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AdminRoleId)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CreatedAt)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UpdatedAt)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AdminId)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AdminFirstName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AdminLastName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AdminEmail)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AdminUserName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AdminPassword)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AdminContactNumber)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AdminDesignation)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AdminRoleId)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CreatedAt)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UpdatedAt)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Update", "UpdateAdmin", item) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteAdmin", item)
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

The below code is for the the admin controller method - ViewAdmin:

```
  public ActionResult ViewAdmin()
        {
            List<Models.Administrator> administrators = new List<Models.Administrator>();
            FastFactsTestPortalMapper<Administrator, Models.Administrator> mapobj = new FastFactsTestPortalMapper<Administrator, Models.Administrator>();
            FastFactsTestPortalRepository repObj = new FastFactsTestPortalRepository();
            var lstEntityAdmins = repObj.GetAdministrators();
            foreach(var admin in lstEntityAdmins)
            {
                administrators.Add(mapobj.Translate(admin));
            }
            return View(administrators);
        }
```

Like wise when I update, the cshtml for the update functionality is :

```
@model FastFactsTestPortalMVCApp.Models.Administrator

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "UpdateAdmin";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutAdmin.cshtml";
}

<h2 class="text-center">Update Admin</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveUpdatedAdmin","Admin"))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Administrator</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AdminId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AdminId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AdminId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AdminFirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AdminFirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AdminFirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AdminLastName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AdminLastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AdminLastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AdminEmail, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AdminEmail, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AdminEmail, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AdminUserName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AdminUserName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AdminUserName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AdminPassword, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AdminPassword, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AdminPassword, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AdminContactNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AdminContactNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AdminContactNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AdminDesignation, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AdminDesignation, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AdminDesignation, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AdminRoleId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AdminRoleId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AdminRoleId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CreatedAt, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CreatedAt, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CreatedAt, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UpdatedAt, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UpdatedAt, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UpdatedAt, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "ViewAdmin")
</div>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

The controller method for the update functionality is

```
 public ActionResult UpdateAdmin(Models.Administrator administrator)
        {
            var admindetails = administrator;
            return View(administrator);
        }

        public ActionResult SaveUpdatedAdmin(Models.Administrator administrator)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    FastFactsTestPortalRepository repObj = new FastFactsTestPortalRepository();
                    FastFactsTestPortalMapper<Models.Administrator, Administrator> mapObj = new FastFactsTestPortalMapper<Models.Administrator, Administrator>();
                    var status = repObj.UpdateAdmin(mapObj.Translate(administrator));
                    if (status)
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("ViewAdmin");

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return View("Error");
                    }
                }

                catch (Exception)
                {
                    return View("Error");
                }
            }
            return View("UpdateAdmin", administrator);

    }
```

The Output which I get is :

**AdminId   AdminFirstName  AdminLastName   AdminEmail  AdminUserName   AdminPassword   AdminContactNumber AdminRoleId**
*1  Srinivas    Muralidharan    sm1043@gmail.com    admin   admin   09677299116 1*

I want to change the AdminRoleId to RoleName : Administrator which is already in the database. Also I wanted to keep the change for all the other functionalities.

Kindly could you explain how to come over such problems?

Comment: You are using Entity framework or something Repository pattern or else?

Comment: Entity framework

Comment: I believe `Administrator` class inside Your `Role` class present. so you can use directly in views. `modelObjects.RolesObject.Property` child object auto-fill by entity framework.

Comment: So is it like model.Role.RoleName?

Comment: Yes, exactly can you please check?

Comment: Gald to help you :) good work bro :)